# Puppet device.conf security

Tags: security, passwords, puppet, cisco, device

Does anyone know what the best security practice's are for managing cisco devices via puppet? The documentation says to place username and password in the /etc/puppet/device.conf file when you define the device. But I doubt any company would like their network infrastructure's username and passwords kept in clear text. The same goes for having SSH keys setup. Is hiera an option here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh keys for connecting only for cisco routers with IOS 15.X.
Firstly, you have to configure IOS SSH:

```
hostname name
ip domain-name name
crypto key generate rsa
!
! Enter length of the key

! define local usernames, use passwords or secrets
!
username cisco password cisco
!
ip ssh version 2
!
line vty 0 4
 login local
```

Secondly, you need to configure ssh keys pair for connecting:

- configure the ssh pubkey-chain, where you can enter the key string (from your SSH public key file) or the key’s hash (which is displayed by the ssh-keygen command). It's easier to  to copy/paste the public key from your id_rsa.pub file into the terminal:

> ```
> R(config)#ip ssh pubkey-chain
> R(conf-ssh-pubkey)#username qwert
> R(conf-ssh-pubkey-user)#key-string
> R(conf-ssh-pubkey-data)#_id_rsa.pu_
> R(conf-ssh-pubkey-data)#exit
> ```

… and let the router convert it into the key hash, which is stored in the configuration:

```
R2#show run | section ssh
ip ssh rsa keypair-name SSH
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
 username pipi
  key-hash ssh-rsa lalala
```

But for other IOS you can use only clear-text password.